# How would I go about continuing my program given the prompt and what I've written so far?

Tags: c++, oop

This is a connect 4 game with a 6 by 7 grid. The problem I'm having right now is figuring out how I continue with the code I've written so far. Right now I've gotten to a point where all the win conditions for the game can be checked, but how do I now implement it such that I can check whether the player is making a valid move, and if it is a valid move, how do I switch the player after the move has been made?

This is the header Connect4.h file.

```
\#ifndef CONNECT4_H
\#define CONNECT4_H

\#include \<iostream\>
\#include \<string\>
\#include \<sstream\>
\#include \<cctype\>
\#include \<iomanip\>
\#include \<cmath\>
using namespace std;

class Connect4 {
private:
static const int ROWS = 6;              // determines how many rows for the entire board
static const int COLS = 7;              // determines how many cols for the entire board
static const char BLANK = '\*';      // creates blank indicides on the board // make it square brackets
static const char Player1 = 'X';        // creates token for player 1
static const char Player2 = 'O';        // creates token for player 2
char board\[ROWS\]\[COLS\];
int piecesInCol\[COLS\];
char currentPlayer;
void CopyBoard(const Connect4& other);  // Copies the board from another game
bool IsValidMove(int col) const;        // Checks if a move is valid
bool HasHorizontalWinner() const;       // Checks if there's a winner horizontally
bool HasVerticalWinner() const;         // Checks if there's a winner vertically
bool HasDiagonalWinner() const;         // Checks if there's a winner diagonally

public:
Connect4();                                                                 // default constructor
Connect4(const Connect4& other);                                            // Copy constructor
Connect4& operator=(const Connect4& other);                                 // Assignment operator
\~Connect4();                                                                // Destructor
bool HasWinner() const;                                                     // Checks if there's a winner
bool HasMove() const;                                                       // identifies blank spaces on board
bool MakeMove(int col);                                                     // Makes a move in the specified column
void Reset();                                                               // Resets the game
char CurrentPlayer() const;                                                 // Returns the current player's token
std::string ToString() const;                                               // Returns the board as a string
friend std::ostream& operator\<\<(std::ostream& os, const Connect4& game);    // Output stream operator

};

// default constructor
Connect4::Connect4()
{
for(int i=0; i\<ROWS; i++)
{
for(int j=0; j\<COLS; j++)
{
board\[i\]\[j\] = BLANK;
}
}
for (int i = 0; i \< COLS; i++)
{
piecesInCol\[i\] = 0;
}
}

//Copy Constructor
Connect4::Connect4(const Connect4& other)
{
currentPlayer = other.currentPlayer;
for(int i=0; i\<ROWS; i++) { // row
for(int j=0; j\<COLS; j++) { // col
board\[i\]\[j\] = other.board\[i\]\[j\];
}
}
for (int j = 0; j \< COLS; j++)
{
piecesInCol\[j\] = other.piecesInCol\[j\];
}
}

//assignment operator empty right now

// check for diagonal win top left -\> bottom right
bool Connect4::HasDiagonalWinner() const
{
for (int row = 0; row \<= ROWS - 4; row++)
{
for (int col = 0; col \<= COLS - 4; col++)
{
char token = board\[row\]\[col\];
if (token == BLANK)
{
continue;
}
if (token == board\[row+1\]\[col+1\] && board\[row+2\]\[col+2\] && board\[row+3\]\[col=3\])
{
return true;
}
}
}

// check for diagonal win top right -\> bottom left
for(int row=0; row\<=ROWS-4; row++)
{
for (int col = COLS - 1; col \>= 3; --col)
{
char token = board\[row\]\[col\];
if (token == BLANK)
{
continue;
}
if (token == board\[row+1\]\[col-1\] &&
board\[row+2\]\[col-2\] &&
board\[row+3\]\[col-3\]) {
return true;
}
}
}
return false;
}

// checks to see if horizontal winner
bool Connect4::HasHorizontalWinner() const
{
for(int row=0; row\<=ROWS; row++)
{
for(int col = 0; col \<= COLS; col++)
{
char token = board\[row\]\[col\];
if (token == BLANK)
{
continue;
}
if (token == board\[row\]\[col+1\] &&
token == board\[row\]\[col+2\] &&
token == board\[row\]\[col+3\]) {
return true;
}
}
}
return false;
}

// checks to see if vertical winner
bool Connect4::HasVerticalWinner() const
{
for(int row=0; row\<=ROWS; row++)
{
for(int col = 0; col \<= COLS; col++)
{
char token = board\[row\]\[col\];
if (token == BLANK)
{
continue;
}
if (token == board\[row+1\]\[col\] &&
token == board\[row+2\]\[col\] &&
token == board\[row+3\]\[col\]) {
return true;
}
}
}
return false;
}

\#endif
```

Comment: Your first step before writing any more code is to fix the very poor code formatting and get rid of all the errant \ characters.

Comment: Please convert your text to plain ASCII text.  For example convert `\#` to `#`.